# JavaScript function of add new information when you scroll to the bottom, didnt work as i expected

Tags: javascript

i write a script at JavaScript, that when i scroll to the bottom (minus 200px) of the page, it will add for me more information with AJAX.

my problem is that when i in the area of the botton-200px, its call to the ajax a lot of times, but i need that it will call to the AJAX function just 1 time, everytime that you are in this area (i hope that you understand me).

(everytime that i come to the bottom, i need it to call to the ajax function!)

how can i solve this?

**no metter, i solve this problem!**

---

this is the full source:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = scrollPage;
document.write("<div id='sizeOfPage'></div><div id='sizeOfWindow' style='position:fixed; bottom:0px;'></div>");
function scrollPage() {
    sizeOfPage = document.getElementById('sizeOfPage').offsetTop;
    sizeOfWindow = document.getElementById('sizeOfWindow').offsetTop;
    scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset+sizeOfWindow;

    if (scrollPosition >= sizeOfPage-200) {
        ajax('refPosts.php', '1', true, 'posts');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var reEnteredBottom = false;

window.onscroll = scrollPage;
document.write("<div id='sizeOfPage'></div><div id='sizeOfWindow' style='position:fixed; bottom:0px;'></div>");
function scrollPage() {
    sizeOfPage = document.getElementById('sizeOfPage').offsetTop;
    sizeOfWindow = document.getElementById('sizeOfWindow').offsetTop;
    scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset+sizeOfWindow;

    if (scrollPosition >= sizeOfPage-200 && !reEnteredBottom) {
        reEnteredBottom = true;
        ajax('refPosts.php', '1', true, 'posts');
    } else if(scrollPosition < sizeOfPage - 200) reEnteredBottom = false;
}
</script>
```

Just introduce a new variable that tracks whether you have left the bottom part and only execute the AJAX code when you have and re-enter, not when just normally scrolling

Comment: thanks but its didnt good for me, becouse it will add new information just 1 time, and after that, when i come again to the bottom, it will do nothind.

Comment: Maybe you need a different way to determine where you scrolled, I didn't try to understand the way you set that up. What you should take as a takeaway is the pattern to identify whether you're re-entering or just scrolling

Comment: oops, i didnt see the `else if`, but its still not works good. its still load the ajax call too much times, and not just 1 time every time that you in the bottom-200px

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?